# How to change upper case letters to lower case letters and spaces to underscores

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, replace, lowercase

I would like to change the upper case string characters in a variable to lower case and replace the spaces with "_". I know I can use an 'if' statement for all instances but this would take too long. It is to save the input of a user to a filename i.e.

```
user_selection = 'Barracuda Limited'  # what I have
save_name == 'barracuda_limited'       # what I want
```

Note: I have read through the page on how to post and am trying my best, but I have just started to learn coding and am having trouble trying to frame my questions.

Comment: This could have easily been answered by googling and/or looking at the python docs. Nothing personal, but it's pretty simple to Google this.

Comment: Understandable but please note, I wouldn't have posted this if I could find the answer online first. I typed in "how to change upper case to lower case, Python" among many other variations and could not find the right syntax to use. This is my first week trying to code and I have no idea where I should be using brackets for functions, dots or both like in this example. It might seem easy to adapt other answers for those who do this for a living but many beginners will find it hard to interpret code that isn't specific to their question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is straightforward, using the [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) methods:

```
>>> user_selection = 'Barracuda Limited'
>>> save_name = user_selection.lower().replace(' ', '_')
>>> save_name
'barracuda_limited'
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get your desired data you can do something like this:

```
user_selection = 'Barracuda Limited':
save_name = "_".join(k.lower() for k in user_selection.split())
# save_name is: 'barracuda_limited'
```

Comment: Splitting the string up and then joining it back together is quite inefficient compared to using the built-in `str.replace()` method, and your solution will replace *multiple* consecutive whitespace characters (including tabs and newlines) with a *single* underscore (which might be what OP wants, but isn't what they've asked for).

Comment: Yes you're right. But i thought that the OP want a general solution that can be used whenever he want with a random data (not only with the data in his question). Your solution is quite efficient and easy to use.